# Random 2D Cityscape generator, how do I randomly generate?

Tags: java, random, 2d, processing

I have to randomly generate a cityscape with 3 layered functions in processing. I'm doing so by drawing each floor in a loop that runs until a random integer, and doing the same thing with floors per building. Currently, the floors are initially randomly generated, but then they eventually fill out to the maximum of the random function. How do I get it so they stay random? Thanks, code is below.

```
int boxX = 0;
int boxY = 479;
void setup() {
  size(1000, 500);
  background(255); 
  frameRate(10);
}

void draw() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    building(boxX, boxY);
    translate(150, 0);
  }
}
void room(int boxX, int boxY) {
  rect(boxX, boxY, 20, 20);
}

void floor(int boxX, int boxY) {
  int randomNum = (int)random(3, 5);
  for (int i=0; i<= randomNum; i++) {
    room(boxX, boxY);
    boxX += 20;
  }
}

void building(int boxX, int boxY) {
  int randomNum = int(random(10, 20));
  for (int i = 0; i < randomNum; i++) {
    floor(boxX, boxY);
    boxY -= 20;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're generating a random cityscape every single frame, but you're never clearing out old frames. That means that your new frames are just drawn right on top of your old frames.

To better see what I'm talking about, clear out the old frames by adding a call to `background()` as the first line in your `draw()` function:

```
void draw() {
  background(200);
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    building(boxX, boxY);
    translate(150, 0);
  }
}
```

You need to take a step back and ask yourself exactly what you want to happen. Do you want to generate a new cityscape every frame? If so leave the call to `background()` in. Do you just want to generate a single cityscape? If so then call `noLoop()` to prevent the `draw()` function from being called more than once, or store your cityscape in a data structure that you redraw every frame instead of regenerating.

Comment: Thanks very much! I used noLoop.